# Column Alignment in dataTable

Tags: jquery, alignment

I am using `p:columnGroup` for header column in `p:dataTable`. I have implemented a vertical and horizontal scroll bar in this table. Now when I take horizontal scroll to the right most then the column containing data does not aligned vertically with the header column due to vertical scroll bar which is rendered below header columns. so there is discrepancy in the alignment (gap = width of vertical scroll bar)

Here is the code

```
<p:columnGroup id="columnGroup" type="header">
             <p:row>
        <p:column id="emptyColumnHeader">&nbsp;</p:column>
        <p:column colspan="3" headerText="General" />
        <p:column colspan="4" headerText="Article" />
        <p:column colspan="5" headerText="Sample" />
         </p:row>
```

using jquery to implement scrolling

```
var oTable2 = $($currentTableId).find('table').dataTable({

            "sScrollX" : "100%",
            "sScrollY" : "350",
            "bAutoWidth" : false,

            "bScrollCollapse" : true,
            "bPaginate" : false,
            "bSort" : false,
            "sInfo" : "",
            "sInfoEmpty" : ""
        });
        oTable2.height("200");
        var oFC = new FixedColumns(oTable2, {
            "iLeftColumns" : 4,
            "sHeightMatch" : "auto",
            "iLeftWidth" : 500
        });
```

Can anyone suggest the solution please?

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue. And had very little time to resolve it. This is a quick solution that helped me.

After rendering your datatable write these two lines :

```
// Considering your datatable id as 'myTableId'
$('#myTableId_next').click();
$('#myTableId_previous').click();
```

Note : This is not the best solution, but definitely a quick one.